# Why can't I call the reducer directly?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I read some introduction blog post on redux and its priciples. I still don't know why the reducer should not be called directly, but by calling an action function with data in the parameter. What is the advantage?

action

```
export function setPerson(personData) {
  return {
   type: actionTypes.SET_PERSON,
   personData
  };
}
```

Comment: You never really call reducers directly because there should be no reason to. Reducers calculate the new state, and there shouldn't ever be a need to access the new state before it is set. Are you perhaps talking about action creators, which as you've shown, return an object that describes an action? That's just a wrapped for reuse and readability. You can always dispatch a plain object instead of calling an action creator, it's just there for usability.

Comment: if you call reducer directly you will not alter redux state, it’s just a function that takes state and action as arguments, and returns the next state of the app. **Reducers specify how the application's state changes in response to actions sent to the store.**

Comment: you can read more about data flow [here](https://redux.js.org/docs/basics/DataFlow.html)

Comment: Actually, at some situations you can and should call a reducer directly. but you do it from another reducer. this pattern called [reducer composition](https://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html#splitting-reducers)

Comment: Your reducers are **ALL** called when an action is dispatched and then only one of them gets to return a new state depending on the action passed. The whole point of this pipeline is to make it easier to manage state especially is large applications. You don't have to worry about anything else when writing your reducers except for the inputs coming in. You also don't care how your action is dealing with state after you dispatch it. each piece of code is doing one thing for this pipeline to be reusable and manageable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several reasons:

- The current state value is kept inside the store, so it can only be updated by running the reducer.  The reducer can only be run by calling `store.dispatch()`.  So, part of the answer is "that's how it's designed to work".
- The "Flux Architecture" introduced the idea of plain object actions, and Redux was designed to be an implementation of the Flux Architecture.
- Plain object actions enable many key features of Redux:

  - A history log of events that occurred over time, and how those events correlate to state changes
  - Enabling time-travel debugging, in the form of changing the sequence of dispatched actions
  - Allowing middleware to interact with the actions as they are dispatched, enabling logging, modification of actions, and other centralized behavior
  - Enabling serialization and persistence of behavior, such as synchronizing multiple stores across a network.